# Unable to "Create Report in Design View" in LibreOffice Base

Tags: libreoffice-base

I am unable to create a report in design view. When I click on this option nothing happens. The "Use Wizard to Create Report" option works fine as do all other options. I am using Linux Mint 17.2. I tried a profile reset without success.

Comment: I had a problem with the Oracle Report Builder Extension: newer versions of LibreOffice Base have the Report Builder "built in" and have both the "built in" version and the extension caused my reports to not work.  Uninstalling the extension for Oracle Report Builder fixed my problem.  You might check out Tools→Extension Manager and, if Oracle Report Builder is there, delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have Oracle Report Builder installed. However I found the following bug report for ubuntu 12.04 and it appears the same applies to Mint 17.2. After applying the fix I am now able to create a report in design view.
[Libreoffice-report-builder](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/992232)